# Using WinUI 3 in a Visual Studio desktop MFC class library project

Tags: c#, dll, mfc, c++-winrt, winui-3

To extend a third party MFC application I must create a desktop static MFC class library (i.e. dll).  Using C++ I successfully completed the logic/backend portion of the project.  With the aid of C++/winrt nuget package, I had a wealth of APIs that helped. Note my preferred language is C# with Visual Studio should that be relevant.

For the user interface I would like to completely use WINUI 3 instead of MFC APIs.  Currently a desktop win32 WINUI solution must include a packaging project (i.e. MSIX) to get the required APP ID.  This seems like a fundamental problem since I must produce a MFC dll and not a full blown application/exe install.  If necessary I can wait (Not preferred) for Windows APP SDK 1.0, but I need to confirm this solves my problem and a release is coming.

Alternatively I may need to use [WinRT XAML hosting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/using-the-xaml-hosting-api#host-a-custom-uwp-control) (XAML islands). This has limitation, but is this still the best/only viable option for WINUI in a C++ MFC desktop unpackaged app?

Basically how can I best utilize WINUI 3 in my MFC class library project?

Comment: This sounds like what you *really* want is a way to give your application an identity. Though it's unclear what MFC is left then. You've moved the backend code to the Windows Runtime already, and are planning to move the UI to WinUI 3.

Comment: From what you write it sounds that islands is what you want. Haven't tried that myself though.